# Foreach loops in PHP and Joomla

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla

I'm currently managing the display of MySQL content in HTML with foreach loop like this :

```
<?php
  echo "<table class=\"tableau\">
        <tr bgcolor=\"#a72333\" class=\"first\">
            <th>Repere</th>
            <th>Niveau</th>
            <th>Enseigne</th>
            <th>Activités</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>";

$db= JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'SELECT baseData, sid, fid FROM XXXX_sobipro_field_data';
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($results as &$value) {
    if ($value->sid == 55) {
        if ($value->fid == 20) {
            $repere = $value->baseData; 
        }
        if ($value->fid == 16) {
            $level = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 22) {
            $title = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 17) {
            $activity = $value->baseData;
        }
        if ($value->fid == 21) {
            $display = $value->baseData;
        }
    }
[...]
 // It ends at if ($value->fid == 83)
}
```

So I name my variable like this `$title_NUM`, `$activity_NUM`, ..., where `_NUM` is a number starting at "nothing", it ends at 24 for now, but it could be more if I have more data in my table.

After I get the data I display the html like this :

```
if ($display == 1) {
    echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#eaeaeb\">
        <td valign=\"top\">".$repere."</td>
        <td align=\"top\">".$level."</td>
        <td valign=\"top\"><a data-lightbox=\"width:600;type:iframe;\" href=\"LINK\">".$title."</a></td>
        <td align=\"top\">".$activity."</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

And the same happens here I'm displaying each linke of the html "by hand" , O don't have any loop to do the job.

Is there a way to do the job with only loops ?

Comment: I'm unable to understand what exactly you are trying to do. Can you be little more specific. I mean try to explain it with example instead of pasting the whole code. I would be happy to help you with this. :)

Comment: what is contained in "display"? Is it like an ID? If yes, you could just leave out "display" and echo the HTML as you collect the data from the array. If displaying the data depends on "display", you could either already exclude it in the query (WHERE display = '1') or get the display value first and then echo the data as you collect it. I'll be happy to elaborate if that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i understand so far is that you have
`$title1` , `$title2` , `$title3` , `...`
you want to do loop for it

see this example

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=8;$i++)//note it start from 0 to 8
    ${'test'.$i}=5*$i;
$test9=5*9;
echo "let's test <br/>";
echo $test0.'<br/>';
for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)//note it start from 1 to 9
    echo ${'test'.$i}.'<br/>';
?>
```